# Making vs2010 project dll compatible with visual studio 2012

Tags: asp.net-4.5

I have created a project using vs2010 ,now i am using vs2012 but i am geting error as

```
Error   1   The type 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Instrumentation.IInstrumentationEventProvider' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. C:\Users\dcss3\Desktop\21nov2012\NuggettsCloud\AppDAL\AssetCardDAL.cs   103 18  AppDAL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the assembly reference Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common to your project. It can be done by right clicking the reference node in your project and selecting 'add reference'.

Comment: still not working ,why am i geting these issue is this a version issue 4.0 to 4.5